# cheeriojs select tags that are not inside another specified tag

Tags: node.js, cheerio

consider the following code

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const xml = `<foo id="1" a="blah"><updateHistory><foo id="1" a="blah"/><foo id="1" a="blah"/><foo id="1" a="blah"/><foo id="1" a="blah"/></updateHistory>Figs. 1-9</foo>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, { normalizeWhitespace: true, xmlMode: true }, false);
const elements = $('foo');
const num = elements.length;
if (num) console.log(num); // prints 5 because there are 5 'foo' tags
```

But I don't want anything from inside `<updateHistory></updateHistory>` tags. In other words, I want `element` to contain only the first `<foo>` tag and `num` to be 1. How can I do that?

update: so, turns out I can do something like this

```js
for (let i = 0, j = elements.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (elements[i].parent.name !== 'updateHistory') {
        // this is the tag I want    
    }
}
```

is there a better way?

Comment: did you try `$('foo').children().first()`. these also: `$('foo').first()` or `$('foo').eq(0)`. see here https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/0c787f656a2cd44ca36a1ab70dccc7c8d98340de/lib/api/traversing.js#L709-L722

Comment: I didn't know of that… thanks for telling me. However, while it may work in some cases for me, it is not really bulletproof because it is not necessarily the first matching element I want. Instead, I specifically *don't* want anything inside `<updateHistory>`. Hence I think my approach might be less prone to failure

Comment: well, it's a child tag, so not sure how to exclude it.. if that's what you have in mind. either way, I think it's a matter of choosing the most appropriate selector..

Comment: I think it's `:not(updateHistory) > foo` But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method is fine. Written a bit more succinctly:

```js
const elements = [...$("foo")]
  .filter(e => e.parent.name !== "updateHistory");
```

This would fail if `<foo>` is a transitive descendant rather than an immediate child of `<updateHistory>`. If you require handling this, you could traverse all the way up the tree to check for the presence of an `<updateHistory>` ancestor:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const xml = `
<foo id="1" a="blah">
  <updateHistory>
    <bar>
      <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
      <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
      <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
      <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
    </bar>
  </updateHistory>
  Figs. 1-9
</foo>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true});
const elements = [...$("foo")]
  .filter(e => {
    for (; e; e = e.parent) {
      if (e.name === "updateHistory") {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  });
console.log(elements.length); // => 1
```

Here's another approach, working top-down rather than bottom-up:

```js
const xml = `
<foo id="1" a="blah">
  <updateHistory>
    <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
    <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
    <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
    <foo id="1" a="blah"/>
  </updateHistory>
  Figs. 1-9
</foo>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true});
const elements = [...$("foo")]
  .filter(e => $(e).find("updateHistory").length);
console.log(elements.length); // => 1
```

This returns all `<foo>` which have an `<updateHistory>` descendant, and may or may not make sense for your use case. You can also do this with CSS rather than `.filter()` using `$("foo:has(updateHistory)");`